# How to input a date later than 2290.12.31 in KDB?

Tags: date, kdb

I'm using KDB+ 3.2 (32-bit), and I can't seem to execute an expression with a date greater than `2290.12.31`:

```
q) 2291.01.01
An error occurred during execution of the query.
The server sent the response:
2291.01.01
```

Any ideas why and how to fix?

Comment: It might help to know *why* you need dates so far in the future.

Comment: In my financial dataset there are a few rare cases where a [bond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond_(finance)) has a maturity date later than `2290.12.31`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since dates are stored as integer internally, I was able to create the 2291.01.01 using below.

```
q)\`date$106285  
2290.12.31  
q)\`date$106286  
2291.01.01  
q)type `date$106286  
-14h
```